# Onclick problems in list elements

Tags: javascript, onclick, html-lists

Okey so I got a List that's beeing created depending on the information from a database. the end result looks something like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li onclick="testFunction(1, "text")">Title1</li>
  <li onclick="testFunction(2, "text")">Title2
    <ul class="sub">
      <li onclick="testFunction(3, "text")">Title3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li onclick="testFunction(4, "text")">Title4</li>
</ul>
```

Now, I want to send the id and the text to the function "testFunction". This works great with the primaty li elements, but when I click a li element from the "sub" class, the function is first run on the pressed li element and then on the li element above. So in this case, if i press Title3, the function will first be ran with id 3 and then with id 2 witch is the parent element. I am thinking it's somehow accessing the whole li tree somehow but can't really understand why. any thoughts?

Comment: You can catch the event and stop its bubbling up the DOM tree: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_5.3A_Event_Propagation

Comment: Not sure I see whant you mean  Pranav Kapoor, I need the ul element inside the li element to make it understand its a sub item, don't I ?

Comment: Yes, but isn't that what I got? 2 ul elements never follow eachother.